# Is there an equivalent utility class for ByteArrayDataInput and ByteArrayDataOutput in C++?

Tags: java, c++, c++11, networking, packet

I am doing some networking, and I need some organization in my packets.
Sending raw bytes and having no abstraction is real difficult.

For java developers, do you know equivalent classes to ByteArrayDataInput and ByteArrayDataOutput in C++?

If you aren't familiar with them, could you show me how I could go about coding them.

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
class packetreader
{
public:
    bool read_bool(int index);

    char read_byte(int index);

    short read_short(int index);

    int read_int(int index);

    long read_long(int index);

    float read_float(int index);

    double read_double(int index);

    std::string read_string(int index);
};
```

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
class packetwriter
{
    void write_bool(int index, bool value);

    void write_byte(int index, char value);

    void write_short(int index, short value);

    void write_int(int index, int value);

    void write_long(int index, long value);

    void write_float(int index, float value);

    void write_double(int index, double value);

    void write_string(int index, std::string value);
};
```

Those are my header files, I now need help implementing them.
And how could I go about efficiently reading/writing arrays of these types?
like write_double_array(array) and read_double_array(array)?
Writing it with write_double(array[i]) for every element in the array?
Thanks.

Comment: There are a [significant number of awesome c++ frameworks for networking](https://github.com/fffaraz/awesome-cpp#networking), could one of those work for you?

Comment: I would prefer to learn how to create this feature, and understand it so I could recreate it in other programming languages, but most importantly need it in C++.

Comment: @purplex what exactly you want to learn? read data through network? extract data from bytes?

Comment: Yea have bytes, and extract this data that was inserted from the client IN THE SAME order it was written in.

Comment: if endianness is what bother you, simply write them byte-by-byte and retrieve in the same order, no way to get it wrong.

Comment: or simply use plain text and leave endianness to system/protocol?

Answer (score 0):

C++ has no standard API for networking. If your program runs on an operating system, then the OS likely provides an API for networking.

C++ also has no standard API for serialisation, which is what I presume `ByteArrayData` classes are for. Serialisation can be implemented with fundamental arithmetic operations.

Comment: How can I learn how to make something like this?
Does what I want already exist open source?
I couldn't find a complete replication of what I need and I can't be bothered scrolling through hundreds of files in large open source network libraries to find this small feature.

Comment: @purplex `How can I learn` Reading books and studying open source implementations are options. `Does what I want already exist open source?` Without a doubt. `I can't be bothered` Seems like this is the core of your problem. `to find this small feature` It's subjective I suppose, but I wouldn't consider this a small feature.

Comment: I am talking about libraries like boost, I'd have to scroll through hundreds of files, compared to other stuff such large libraries offer, this stuff is small.